# How to send MJPEG frames on RTSP

Tags: python, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp, mjpeg

I'm trying to modify the current GStreamer pipeline

```
appsrc name=source caps=video/x-raw, format=BGR,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 name=pay0 pt=96
```

that I'm using in my python RTSP Server, to use MJPEG instead of x264.

In particular, since I read [here](https://gstconf.ubicast.tv/protected/videos/v12561a512c11v03u9ecu2rilqcjcr/attachments/gstconf_2016_an_overview_of_video_encoding_benchmarks_with_gstreamer.pdf) that avenc_mjpeg is the encoder with better performances, I decided to use it.
The first thing I tried was to replace x264enc and its parameters with avenc_mjpeg.

On the other side, in the command I'm using to read the stream (from terminal, by now)

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtsprc location=127.0.0.1:8554/test is-live=true ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_264 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```

I tried to remove h264parse and replace avdec_264 with avdec_mjpeg.

But this don't works.

[Here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Write-opencv-frames-into-gstreamer-rtsp-server-pipeline-td4685382.html) the code I used as inspiration to develop my RTSP server

I'm not an expert with GStreamer pipelines.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

MJPEG is basically a series of JPEG images. So you can convert frames to JPEG and transmit them.

In your case:

```
appsrc name=source caps=video/x-raw, format=BGR,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96
```

And for the receiving side:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtsprc location=127.0.0.1:8554/test is-live=true ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```